# Разбить одну большую функцию

Tags: c++, ооп, winapi, функции, com

У меня есть такой код:

```
bool TestWMI::getBios(QQueue<QPair<QString, QString> > &records)
{
    HRESULT hres;

    hres =  CoInitializeEx(0, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
    if (FAILED(hres) && hres != -2147417850)
    {
        return false;                  // Program has failed.
    }

    hres =  CoInitializeSecurity(
        NULL,
        -1,                          // COM authentication
        NULL,                        // Authentication services
        NULL,                        // Reserved
        RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_DEFAULT,   // Default authentication
        RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IDENTIFY,    // Default Impersonation
        NULL,                        // Authentication info
        EOAC_NONE,                   // Additional capabilities
        NULL                         // Reserved
        );


    if (FAILED(hres) && hres != -2147417831)
    {

        CoUninitialize();
        return false;                    // Program has failed.
    }

    IWbemLocator *pLoc = NULL;

    hres = CoCreateInstance(
        CLSID_WbemLocator,
        0,
        CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
        IID_IWbemLocator, (LPVOID *) &pLoc);

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {

        CoUninitialize();
        return false;                 // Program has failed.
    }

    IWbemServices *pSvc = NULL;

    QString str = "ROOT\\CIMV2";
    if (lpRemoteName != "")
        str = lpRemoteName + "\\" + str;

    BSTR bstr = QStringToBSTR(str);

    hres = pLoc->ConnectServer(
        bstr,
        NULL,    // User name
        NULL,     // User password
        NULL,                              // Locale
        NULL,                              // Security flags
        NULL,// Authority
        NULL,                              // Context object
        &pSvc                              // IWbemServices proxy
        );
    SysFreeString(bstr);

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {

        pLoc->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return false;                // Program has failed.
    }

    hres = CoSetProxyBlanket(
       pSvc,                           // Indicates the proxy to set
       RPC_C_AUTHN_DEFAULT,            // RPC_C_AUTHN_xxx
       RPC_C_AUTHZ_DEFAULT,            // RPC_C_AUTHZ_xxx
       COLE_DEFAULT_PRINCIPAL,         // Server principal name
       RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_PKT_PRIVACY,  // RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_xxx
       RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE,    // RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_xxx
       NULL,                       // client identity
       EOAC_NONE                       // proxy capabilities
    );

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        pSvc->Release();
        pLoc->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return false;               // Program has failed.
    }

    bstr = QStringToBSTR("WQL");
    BSTR bstr1 =  QStringToBSTR("Select * from Win32_BIOS");
    IEnumWbemClassObject* pEnumerator = NULL;
    hres = pSvc->ExecQuery(
        bstr,
        bstr1,
        WBEM_FLAG_FORWARD_ONLY | WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY,
        NULL,
        &pEnumerator);
    SysFreeString(bstr);
    SysFreeString(bstr1);

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        pSvc->Release();
        pLoc->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return false;               // Program has failed.
    }

    hres = CoSetProxyBlanket(
        pEnumerator,                    // Indicates the proxy to set
        RPC_C_AUTHN_DEFAULT,            // RPC_C_AUTHN_xxx
        RPC_C_AUTHZ_DEFAULT,            // RPC_C_AUTHZ_xxx
        COLE_DEFAULT_PRINCIPAL,         // Server principal name
        RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_PKT_PRIVACY,  // RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_xxx
        RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE,    // RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_xxx
        NULL,                       // client identity
        EOAC_NONE                       // proxy capabilities
        );

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        pEnumerator->Release();
        pSvc->Release();
        pLoc->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return false;               // Program has failed.
    }

    IWbemClassObject *pclsObj = NULL;
    ULONG uReturn = 0;

    while (pEnumerator)
    {
        HRESULT hr = pEnumerator->Next(WBEM_INFINITE, 1,
            &pclsObj, &uReturn);

        if(0 == uReturn)
        {
            break;
        }

        VARIANT vtProp;

        pclsObj->Get(L"Name", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);
        records.enqueue(QPair<QString, QString>("Имя БИОСа", QString::fromStdWString(vtProp.bstrVal)));

        VariantClear(&vtProp);

        pclsObj->Release();
        pclsObj = NULL;
    }

    pSvc->Release();
    pLoc->Release();
    pEnumerator->Release();
    if( pclsObj )
    {
        pclsObj->Release();
    }

    CoUninitialize();
}
```

Он выбирает данные только из `Win32_BIOS`, а у меня есть ещё таблиц 15, из которых мне надо брать данные, т.е. меняться будут только строки

```
BSTR bstr1 =  QStringToBSTR("Select * from Win32_BIOS");
```

и (этих обычно больше, поскольку параметры разные нужны)

```
 pclsObj->Get(L"Name", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);
    records.enqueue(QPair<QString, QString>("Имя БИОСа", QString::fromStdWString(vtProp.bstrVal)));
```

Я пробовал вынести создание `COM` в конструктор класса и не пересоздавать его каждый раз, но в таком случае происходят утечки память. Я пробовал вынести инициализацию в отдельную функцию и передавать туда указатели, такой способ, по сути, должен работать, потому что я просто копипасщу, но в таком случае у меня вылетает сегфолт на функции `ExecQuery`. У меня уже нет идей, как реализовать так, чтобы не было утечек памяти и не приходилось копипастить 1500+ строк.

Оригинал функции- https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/aa390422(v=vs.85).aspx

P.S. Я не прошу всё написать за меня, хотя и против не буду, главное подскажите, как лучше это реализовать.

P.S.S. Вот пример через функцию, когда вылетает на `ExecQuery`:

```
bool TestWMI::getBios(QQueue<QPair<QString, QString> > &records)
{
    IWbemLocator *pLoc_ = NULL;
    QSharedPointer<IWbemLocator> pLoc(pLoc_);

    IWbemServices *pSvc_ = NULL;
    QSharedPointer<IWbemServices> pSvc(pSvc_);

    init(pLoc.data(), pSvc.data());

    BSTR bstr = QStringToBSTR("WQL");
    BSTR bstr1 =  QStringToBSTR("Select * from Win32_BIOS");
    IEnumWbemClassObject* pEnumerator = NULL;
    qDebug() << "test_1";
    HRESULT hres = pSvc->ExecQuery(
        bstr,
        bstr1,
        WBEM_FLAG_FORWARD_ONLY | WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY,
        NULL,
        &pEnumerator);
    qDebug() << "test_2";
...

bool TestWMI::init(IWbemLocator *pLoc, IWbemServices *pSvc)
{
    HRESULT hres;

    hres =  CoInitializeEx(0, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
    if (FAILED(hres) && hres != -2147417850)
    {
        return false;                  // Program has failed.
    }

    hres =  CoInitializeSecurity(
        NULL,
        -1,                          // COM authentication
        NULL,                        // Authentication services
        NULL,                        // Reserved
        RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_DEFAULT,   // Default authentication
        RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IDENTIFY,    // Default Impersonation
        NULL,                        // Authentication info
        EOAC_NONE,                   // Additional capabilities
        NULL                         // Reserved
        );


    if (FAILED(hres) && hres != -2147417831)
    {

        CoUninitialize();
        return false;                    // Program has failed.
    }

    hres = CoCreateInstance(
        CLSID_WbemLocator,
        0,
        CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
        IID_IWbemLocator, (LPVOID *) &pLoc);

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {

        CoUninitialize();
        return false;                 // Program has failed.
    }

    QString str = "ROOT\\CIMV2";
    if (lpRemoteName != "")
        str = lpRemoteName + "\\" + str;

    BSTR bstr = QStringToBSTR(str);

    hres = pLoc->ConnectServer(
        bstr,
        NULL,    // User name
        NULL,     // User password
        NULL,                              // Locale
        NULL,                              // Security flags
        NULL,// Authority
        NULL,                              // Context object
        &pSvc                              // IWbemServices proxy
        );
    SysFreeString(bstr);

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {

        pLoc->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return false;                // Program has failed.
    }

    hres = CoSetProxyBlanket(
       pSvc,                           // Indicates the proxy to set
       RPC_C_AUTHN_DEFAULT,            // RPC_C_AUTHN_xxx
       RPC_C_AUTHZ_DEFAULT,            // RPC_C_AUTHZ_xxx
       COLE_DEFAULT_PRINCIPAL,         // Server principal name
       RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_PKT_PRIVACY,  // RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_xxx
       RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE,    // RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_xxx
       NULL,                       // client identity
       EOAC_NONE                       // proxy capabilities
    );

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        pSvc->Release();
        pLoc->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return false;               // Program has failed.
    }
}
```

Comment: @МишаковМаксим Офтопом замечу, что не стоит смешивать код специфичный для разных экосистем. В вашем случае это WinApi + COM и QT.

Comment: @Cerbo То есть не использовать Qt, а только чистый C++, для возможности использования этого кода в другом проекте, не притягивая за ним Qt ради пары классов?

Comment: @МишаковМаксим Да, и еще можно на стандартную библиотеку положится. По-хорошему развязывать это все нужно, хотя если проект не большой и/или одноразовый, то не стоит заморачиваться.

Comment: @МишаковМаксим, так-то смартпоинтеры нужны для того, чтобы НЕ звать руками всякие `pLoc->Release();`. Для этого нужны удалители. Кроме того, вы их сначала инициализируете нулевыми значениями (пустыми сырыми указателями), а потом разыменовывать пытаетесь (звать `pSvc->ExecQuery`, например).

Comment: @free_ze Я не знал, пока не увидел ваш ответ, что можно писать кастомный удалитель, сейчас попробую, спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Надеюсь, вы можете использовать >=C++11 (=

Начните с того, что каждый сырой указатель (`IWbemLocator`, `IWbemServices`, `BSTR`, `IEnumWbemClassObject`, `IWbemClassObject`) оберните в `std::unique_ptr` или `std::shared_ptr` с кастомным удалителем. Например:

```
IWbemLocator *pLoc = nullptr;

hres = CoCreateInstance(
    CLSID_WbemLocator,
    0,
    CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
    IID_IWbemLocator, (LPVOID *) &pLoc);

auto deleter = [](IWbemLocator* p) { p->Release(); };

std::unique_ptr<IWbemLocator, decltype(deleter)> spLoc1(pLoc, deleter);
// или
// std::shared_ptr<IWbemLocator> spLoc2(pLoc, deleter);
```

Эти умные указатели сами вызовут `Release` и очистят память, когда текущая функция завершиться. Извлекать сырой указатель (для передачи в другие функции) можно с помощью `spLock1.get()`.

Все, теперь вы не боитесь утечек памяти и можете начать пилить на функции.
В коде отлично просматривается структура: каждый этап, как вы перезаписываете `hres` можно изолировать в функции и возвращать оттуда `std::unique_ptr`. Зависимости можно передавать сырыми указателями (память-то у нас живет, пока не завершится основной метод). Передачу параметров и извлечение результата можно оформить в виде коллбеков.

Comment: "Все, теперь вы не боитесь утечек памяти..." О-хо-хо, их нужно всегда боятся.

Comment: @Cerbo, их нужно уважать, а не бояться)

Comment: Можете подсказать, что за ошибка? Код такой же, как у Вас error: no matching function for call to 'std::unique_ptr<IWbemLocator>::unique_ptr(IWbemLocator*&, TestWMI::getBios(QQueue<QPair<QString, QString> >&)::<lambda(IWbemLocator*)>&)'
     std::unique_ptr<IWbemLocator> spLoc1(pLoc, deleter);

Comment: @МишаковМаксим, да, прошу прощения, при создании `std::unique_ptr` нужно как параметр шаблона указать также тип удалителя. Поправил код в ответе.

Comment: хм, теперь всё работает, но вылетает на строке  p->Release();. Т.е. функция завершается, он пытается сделать Release() и выкидывает неизвестную ошибку. Все ручные Release'ы я удалил

Comment: @МишаковМаксим, нужно убедиться, что умный указатель инициализируется действительным адресом. То есть сначала получаем ресурс на сырой указатель и только потом его передаем в конструктор умного.

Comment: Да, всё так, я инициализирую его в CoCreateInstance, ошибок там нет. Если руками написать Release() в конце функции, то ошибок нет

Comment: @МишаковМаксим, покажите актуальный код.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67871/discussion-between---and-free-ze).